# Overwrite configuration for Spring project from outside

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I'm developing a Spring application which shall be used by any kind of other application, no matter if that is a Spring project, a web application or even a simple single-class console application. The application who uses my project will just have to add the JAR file with my application.

So my project has a static factory class that gets and returns a bean from its Spring context which acts as an access object to access all public available functions of my project.
That part is already working.

But I need the developer of the application that uses my JAR to be able to overwrite certain configurations in my project without editing the config files in the JAR itself. At the moment those settings should be overwritable:
- the data source and hibernate bean configuration
- the jasypt (encryption) bean configuration
- the log4j settings

How do I make those settings overwriteable with configs from outside the jar?

Greetings
touchdown

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a good solution would be a configuration that the user could override, for this take a look into:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java

Specially to @Configuration and @Bean

Maybe you could have a configuration class implemented and the user can override it. After extending the class and overwrite some methods that provides some beans the user shall inform it to your factory that will do nothing else than

`new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(userConfigurationClass);`

Comment: If I understand that correctly the user who will use my JAR will have to create his own configuration class and pass it to the factory method? I can't expect that from the user. The requirement is, that the user will only have to place his overwrite-config-files into his project's classpath. At most I can expect him to pass a foldername where the config files are to my factory method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the complete configuration, than the easyest way would be to have a parametrized factory that takes an alternative configuration file as its argument.

If you need it a bit more fine grain (lets say up to 10 parts), than you can split your application xml in several smaller once, and use again a configurable factory that allows to exchange the smaller xml files.

Comment: I already splitted the context XMLs using the <import ... /> tag in the main "application-context.xml". But I think that just searches for files in the same directory...

Comment: but I like user1001027 much more than mine.

Answer (score 0):

So I got a solution that is working for me.
I put an general import for override context-XMLs at the bottom of my main application context:

```
<import resource="classpath*:project/package/config/override/or-*.xml" />
```

So all the user has to do is to create the package "project/package/config/override" in his classpath (e.g. resource folder) and place matching XML files in it with new bean definitions.